# The difference between the javascript normal variable and the variable with a dollar sign

Tags: javascript

The question about javascript varabile with a dollar sign has been answered by a couple of times.

In short, the dollar sign plays as an identifier in javascript variable.

However, I was wondering are there more differences between the normal variable and the variable with dollar sign?

Behind the scene, will they have different memory location mechanism? or some other else.

Thanks for any reply. : )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A dollar sign has no specific meaning in JS. Usually it is used to distinguish jQuery objects from other variables but it's just a practice, not a rule.

The JS interpreter doesn't make any difference between "normal" variables and dollar variables; no different memory location or anything else, they are just common variables.

Comment: Thanks Uby. I am clear with these two now.

Comment: And underscore js uses _ as iden tifier. @samLin always check the green box if you are satisfied.

Comment: Thanks. I think I have learnt this knowledge from here.